# Improving the conditions needed before sending an email from Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I came up with some code to send email when column AJ is true. Initially it worked perfectly, but after I add in more guards, it only sends email to the first row.

What i want to achieve:

1. People will send request and details will be shown in "Form responses 4",
2. I would approve, it by indicating `TRUE` in the last column.
3. I click a button to run the script
4. Rows with `TRUE` have data emailed to the email address associated with the row

The code doesn't fully work: if there are three people who should get emailed, only the first will get an email. How can I modify my guards to email everyone whose row has `TRUE`?

---

```
function testing(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form 
Responses 4");

  for (var i = 2 ; i <= lr ; i++){
    var dpt = targetSheet.getRange(i,4).getValue();
    var purpose = targetSheet.getRange(i,5).getValue();
    var p = "HR", d = "DMS", r = "RIM";
    var check = targetSheet.getRange(i, 36).getValue();
    var currentEmail = targetSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
    var currentName = targetSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
    var remark = targetSheet.getRange(i, 35).getValue();
    var qty1 = targetSheet.getRange(i, 7).getValue();
    var qty2 = targetSheet.getRange(i, 10).getValue();
    var qty3 = targetSheet.getRange(i, 14).getValue();
    var qty4 = targetSheet.getRange(i, 17).getValue();
    var qty5 = targetSheet.getRange(i, 21).getValue();
    var qty6 = targetSheet.getRange(i, 24).getValue();
    var qty7 = targetSheet.getRange(i, 26).getValue();
    var qty8 = targetSheet.getRange(i, 28).getValue();
    var qty9 = targetSheet.getRange(i, 30).getValue();
    var qty10 = targetSheet.getRange(i, 32).getValue();

    var ap1 = targetSheet.getRange(i, 8).getValue();
    var ap2 = targetSheet.getRange(i, 11).getValue();
    var ap3 = targetSheet.getRange(i, 15).getValue();
    var ap4 = targetSheet.getRange(i, 18).getValue();
    var ap5 = targetSheet.getRange(i, 22).getValue();
    var ap6 = targetSheet.getRange(i, 25).getValue();
    var ap7 = targetSheet.getRange(i, 27).getValue();
    var ap8 = targetSheet.getRange(i, 29).getValue();
    var ap9 = targetSheet.getRange(i, 31).getValue();
    var ap10 = targetSheet.getRange(i, 33).getValue();

    var S1 = targetSheet.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
    var P1 = targetSheet.getRange(i, 9).getValue();
    var S2 = targetSheet.getRange(i, 13).getValue();
    var P2 = targetSheet.getRange(i, 16).getValue();
    var B = targetSheet.getRange(i, 20).getValue();
    var J = targetSheet.getRange(i, 23).getValue();

    if (dpt == p){
      if (check == true){
        var templateText = /* lots of HTML */;
        var emailText = templateText.replace("name", currentName)
          .replace("purpose", purpose)
          /* Several more replacements */
          .replace("remark", remark);
        MailApp.sendEmail({to: currentEmail, subject: "UPDATES:" + "KIT EXCHANGE REQUISITION FORM", htmlBody: emailText});
      }
    }
    else if (dpt == d){
      if (check == true){
        var templateText = /* More HTML generation */; 
        var emailText = templateText.replace("name", currentName)
          .replace("purpose", purpose)
          /* more replacements */
          .replace("remark",remark);
        MailApp.sendEmail({to: currentEmail, subject: "UPDATES:" + "KIT EXCHANGE REQUISITION FORM", htmlBody: emailText});
      }
    }
    else if (dpt == r){
      if (check == true){
        var templateText = /* HTML generation */;   

        var emailText = templateText.replace("name", currentName)
          .replace("purpose", purpose)
          /* More replacements */
          .replace("remark", remark);
        MailApp.sendEmail({to: currentEmail, subject: "UPDATES:" + "KIT EXCHANGE REQUISITION FORM", htmlBody: emailText});
        return(i);
      }      
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try checking logs or debug your code. Looks like because of `If` conditions your mail sending code is unreachable.

Comment: nothing came out when i tried debugging, instead it just send email. As for logs, it can only reach to the info for first row

Comment: Which means your code after first row is unreachable, check your data and code.

Comment: i can't find the problem to it

Answer (score 2):

You have inserted **return(i);** before the end of the loop. **return()** technically works as the function **exit()** thus your loop is being exited in the very first run and therefore only one email is being sent.

I would suggest you revisit your logic of having the **return(i);** line inside your loop as i dont see how you are using it.

Comment: so return() will do?

Comment: I placed the return(i) or return, either one after the for loop and it works. Now i have another problem, for eg, if the first letter of the name is B, it will substitute with a number or the first letter of the name is missing.